# Python str.format() method not working as expected

Tags: python

I am trying to format some output that I'm printing on the screen. Here's my code:

```
someString = someList[someIndex] +  '{0:<8}'.format('\t') + someList[someOtherIndex]
print someString
```

**My Expected output:**

```
abcdefghi              someOutput
abcde                  someOtherOutput

**OR**
abcdefghi       someOutput
abcde           someOtherOutput
```

**Actual output I get:**

```
abcdefghi              someOutput
abcde          someOtherOutput
```

Q.1: Why am I not getting the expected output? To be specific, why are the entries in second column mis-aligned?
 
Q.2: What should I change in my code to get the expected output?

Additional Info: I am using Python 2.6

Appreciate any help.

Comment: meh I would just do  something like `print "%-16s%s"%("abcde","someOutput")`  ...even if % format is depreciated...it will be around a while

Comment: But why not learn to use the recommended str.format() ?

Comment: Im sure I will when I need to (eg using a version of python that warns about depreciation of this method or a version that no longer supports it...it doesnt look overly hard.. I just like the old version better and will keep using them as long as I am using a python that supports them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply the "filling" on the first string you print, such that it "pushes" the second one always to the same point:

```
someString = '{0:<16}{1}'.format(someList[someIndex], someList[someOtherIndex])
```

Make sure that the filling you require is larger than the longest first word you have to print, though.

What you were doing before is simply printing the first word, then printing a '\t' with filling (which was always the same), and finally the second word.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good online resource that explains all this in detail with examples? I looked at some of the Python documentation but that didn't  contain any examples.

Comment: I'm sorry, the documentation is as detailed as you can get (http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples). For the examples though, you'll have to open up a terminal and try yoursef! It's the best way to learn.